# Is my translation of the phrase "My Gracious mistake" correct?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, translation-check

Let me start by apologising for my terrible attempt at Latin. I don't have any knowledge of the language at all.  However, I do speak Italian so I've taken a bit of my knowledge and lots of Google Translate help to hopefully convert the phrase to Latin (ancient or modern: I'm not that bothered as long as it back-translates to English as the full phrase).

The phrase is **"My Gracious Mistake"**. It's a phrase my best friend uses to describe his kid, since he was a mistake but he loves him.

I've translated it to "mei misereatur error."

How far off the mark am I?  Can it be improved and also how would you pronounce it? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "my gracious mistake"? What's a context where you would say that?

Comment: Are you trying to refer to or play off of the phrase _mea culpa, mea culpa, mea maxima culpa_ ("through my fault, through my fault, through my most grievous fault"), formerly used in the Catholic mass? (Explanation [here](https://liturgyguy.com/2013/07/30/mea-culpa-mea-culpa-mea-maxima-culpa/).)

Comment: BTW, _mei misereatur error_ would mean something like "May the wandering of me be lamented." Google Translate is usually a disaster.

Comment: @BenKovitz the context is a little strange I suppose and you'd never probably use it in a sentence as such.  Its a phrase a my best friend uses to describe his kid as he was a mistake but he loves him. so for their birthday I was going to get something made up for them with the phrase but wanted to do it in a nicer sounding language than English if that makes sense.  In relation to mea culpa that wasn't the intention as to me the meaning or intent of the phrase would be different.

Comment: Ah, that clarifies it. My first thought is _meus lapsus gratiosus_ (using the root of "gracious", which might have just the connotation you want), but I'm only a beginner with Latin. Someone with more of a feel for the language will probably have something spot-on.

Comment: @Dave Welcome to the site! Can you edit your question and put that context in, so others have easier time figuring out a suitable translation?

Comment: @BenKovitz the phrase is still used in the Mass, though

Comment: @Dave is any form of longer sentence usually implied? Like _that was_ my gracious mistake, or _it happened because of_ my gracious mistake?

Comment: Felix culpa? Happy fault  -but it comes with connotations and backstory.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta yeah i've updated the question thanks

Comment: @Rafael usually no he just calls him "my gracious mistake" I always take his usage of it to mean he's thankfull for the result of the mistake.  I suppose you could infer the "that was" part though.

Comment: Please give this a couple days before accepting an answer. That will allow time for people to comment, fix problems, and sort out the most appropriate translation.

Comment: @BenKovitz normally I would but I have to get this to the printers in an hour and the current answer was to me sufficient to cover all the possibilities.

Comment: Ack! I have doubts about _propitius_ but I can't say for sure that it's wrong. I'll post a quick explanation of _lapsus meus gratiosus_ right now (though I'm groggy from just waking up…). (_Felix culpa_ might be better still.)

Comment: @Palizsche I agree that it would not be a good idea to call a child a mistake. In this particular case I would say that they turned out not to be a mistake despite being unplanned. However, I don't think we should filter posts on that basis, apart from very extreme circumstances. Commenting about the consequences of using some expressions is welcome, even if our main focus is on language itself. But others might disagree with me; ask at meta if you want a more definitive answer.

Comment: @Hugh Please post that *felix culpa* as an answer! It really is an answer, so it does not belong in the comment section. Less than perfect answers are more than welcome, so don't set your bar too high.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta, thanks for your reply.  I thought about posting in meta and maybe I still will, though it seems my concern was not shared by others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd translate it as:

> **Propitius error meus**

*(also* **propitius meus error**: *word order doesn't matter that much)*

Where:

- [error](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Derror) (masculine) means mistake. Alternatives: [mendum](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dmendum) (neuter in gender, not as common nor -apparently- as broadly applicable) and [falsum](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0060%3Aentry%3Dfalsum) (also neuter)
- [propitius](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dpropitius) means *favorable, well-disposed, gracious, kind, propitious*, which seems fit for your purpose, also, more freely:

  - [gratiosus](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dgratiosus) (*full of favor, popular, regarded, beloved, agreeable*),
  - [felix](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dfelix1) with a wide range of meanings: from *fruitful* to *lucky* to *happy*.
- [meus](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dmeus) is *my, of me, mine*, etc.

A couple of notes:

- If you chose mendum or falsum instead of error, both adjectives have to change gender accordingly: **propitium/gratiosum/felix meum mendum/falsum**
- Felix [*culpa*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dculpa) (femine, thus *felix culpa mea*) is indeed (as noted by Hugh) a very relevant attested expression quite close in meaning to what you want, but I think it underlines a lack of neutrality a mistake does not: a crime/fault is more than just an accident. Besides, it has a strong religious background some people would want to avoid in a joke.
- [Peccatum](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dpeccatum) (neuter) is also an error, but it means a sin too, and became too strongly associated to the later since Christianity.
- Also, if your friend is addressing the kid (rather than just naming him), it could be **propiti error mi**, if I am not mistaken.

Comment: Are you sure _propitius_ is right? I'm not 100% sure, but from the linked definition, it appears to mean something like "in a good/favorable mood" as in "the boss is in a good mood, i.e. now is a good time to ask the boss for a raise."

Comment: @BenKovitz Although a most prominent meaning of **propitius** applies to well-disposed _people_ as you point, the entry starts with a meaning that applies to things (i.e. application to things is not just by analogy). Since _gratious_ and _propicious_ are listed among the general meanings, I see no harm. _Pax propitia_ is translated as _favoring kindness_ [here](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.02.0110%3Aact%3D4%3Ascene%3D1) (currently looking for more examples)

Comment: The use of **propitius** for things may be seen as just a transfer of qualities from people: (pax tua propitia, auribus propitiis), that is a valid, yet arguably free, way of reading _my gracious mistake_. In the opinion of L&S it is used for the ocean (_propitius et tranquillus Oceanus_) in the sense of the sea itself rather than the deity. Thus _propitius error_ could also be _gratious mistake_ as in the mistake itself being a personification.

Comment: Here's a possibility (I'm not experienced enough to judge if this is right): _propitius_ might be understood as an adjective for _pro_ in the sense of "on behalf of", adding the meaning of "disposed to be that way"—in other words, _primed to take your side._ Hence the primary use of _propitius_ for gods, authority figures, and elements/forces of nature that can either foil or favor your efforts—and the verb [_propitio_](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.04.0059:entry=propitio) to mainly mean appeasing/wheedling such people or things.

Comment: There's even a word [_propitiatrix_](https://books.google.com/books?id=TfQIVjnlFxwC&lpg=PA552&ots=W6IeBZkalJ&dq=propitiatrix&pg=PA552#v=onepage&q=propitiatrix&f=false)—apparently a woman who will help appease an authority to make them propitious to you (maybe Mary could sweet-talk the big guys into going easy on your sins). Notice that _tua pax propitia_ is in a prayer of gratitude to Neptune, for his willingness to calm the winds that had just torn the sails, etc. So I guess my concern boils down to whether _propitius_ strongly invokes a connotation of appeasement and side-taking.

Comment: Although some of the examples cited use _iratus_ and _propitius_ in the same sentence. They do not always oppose both: [propitious vs angered](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.02.0099%3Aact%3D4%3Ascene%3D4). Other cited sources (not in said seeming opposition) are translated as  [favorable](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.02.0018%3Atext%3DDiv.%20Caec.%3Achapter%3D13%3Asection%3D41), [fond](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.02.0112%3Aact%3D1%3Ascene%3D1), etc.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58512/discussion-between-rafael-and-ben-kovitz).

Answer (score 5):

> Lapsus meus gratiosus

A **lapsus** ([noun](http://logeion.uchicago.edu/index.html#lapsus), masc.) is literally a slip, a fall, extended to mean a mistake, including a moral mistake. These senses live in English "relapse", "collapse", and of course "lapse". It appears in phrases such as [*lapsus linguæ*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/lapsus_linguae), "a slip of the tongue". Christianity uses *lapsus* to refer to the fall of [Adam](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=%22lapsus+carnis%22&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8#tbm=bks&q=lapsus+adam), whence some unusual English words like "[prelapsarian](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/prelapsarian#Latin)" and "[postlapsarian](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/postlapsarian#English)". A [*lapsus carnalis*](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=%22lapsus+carnalis%22&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8#q=%22lapsus+carnalis%22&tbm=bks) or [*lapsus carnis*](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=%22lapsus+carnis%22&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8#q=%22lapsus+carnis%22&tbm=bks) is a "sin of the flesh".

**Meus** means "my". I put it here after the noun in order not to give it strong emphasis. Putting a possessive pronoun before the noun tends to make it the main point: *meus lapsus* would mean "*my* mistake", putting most of the emphasis on the father.

**Gratiosus** ([adjective](http://logeion.uchicago.edu/index.html#gratiosus)) is filled with 2,700 years of accumulated positive connotations. [*Gratus*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=gratus&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059) primarily means beloved, dear, pleasing, commonly extended to mean worthy of thanks—a sense that lives in English "gratitude". There is also the well-known Latin phrase [*persona non grata*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persona_non_grata), a person who is not welcome; so, a person who is *grata* is welcome, i.e. gladly admitted into the community. As a noun, [*gratia*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=gratia&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059), it means favor, both that felt by others and favor felt toward another. Christianity picked it up as "[grace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divine_grace)", and it occurs in such established Latin phrases as [*Dei gratia regina*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dei_Gratia_Regina), "Queen by the [grace of God](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/By_the_Grace_of_God)", still used on coins in Commonwealth countries. The suffix *-osus* is like Anglo-Saxon *-ful* in English: it makes an adjective signifying an intensified version of the noun. [*Gratiosus*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=gratiosus&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059) primarily means enjoying the favor of others: popular, beloved—especially, due to agreeable qualities about oneself. In other words, a person who is *gratiosus* is one that others are very glad to have around. This is imported into English as "gracious", a word which your friend appears to have chosen quite propitiously.

So, I'm thinking that combining the connotations of *lapsus* with those of *gratiosus* creates the same benevolent irony of "my gracious mistake". Maybe it's even clearer in Latin!

---

If the father wants to address the son by this phrase, he should use the vocative case, which comes out:

> Mi lapse gratiose

(Note that the *e*'s are both pronounced, like *e* as in Spanish.)